# Exit with code 1 due to network error when trying to convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

As the title says, I am getting an " Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError". Interestingly, this error  when  I attempt to print a pdf from when I access the site using it's full name like 'www.xyz.com'. If I attempt to print the pdf running from my local machine, or from localhost on the server it works fine. But trying for the live weblink is a no go. I updated to 0.12.6 of wkhtmltopdf, using windows server 2012 and my application is written in c# asp dotnet.

I read a few places where it says it may be unable to access some links, but even if I replace everything in the .cshtml page with a single div tag I get the same errror, yet locally everything works fine. Really not sure what the network error can be or what link it's trying to access that's failing

I have trimmed my code to this

```
public ActionResult tP()
{

    var p = new ActionAsPdf("printDummy");
    return p;

}

    public ActionResult printDummy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and thr printDummy view is a simple view with some text that works locally but again not on the server.
Appreciate any assistance in handling this error.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 
    ViewBag.Title = "printDummy";
}

<h2>
    The dog (Canis familiaris when considered a distinct species or Canis lupus familiaris when considered a subspecies of the wolf)[5] is a domesticated carnivore of the family Canidae. It is part of the wolf-like canids,[6] and is the most widely abundant terrestrial carnivore.[7][8][9][10][11]  
</h2>
```

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: What do you mean by "www.webpage.com link."?

Comment: @GuruStron When I go to the web page full name.

Comment: Try explicitly setting page layout with `null` in your `cshtml`.

Comment: @GuruStron I actually did try that, same issue

Comment: Have you tried manually converting this page from your machine using wkhtmltopdf from command line?

Comment: @GuruStron Interestingly, I cant, I can manually convert other web pages but I cant convert any pages from my app. Same Network error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221883/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-niana).